# Group of real analytic isometries of $g$-fold product of the Poincare upper half plane

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $\mathfrak{h}^g$ be the cartesian product of $g$ copies of the Poincare upper half plane. We endow $\mathfrak{h}^g$ with the usual Poincare metric given in local coordinates by $ds^2=\sum_{i=1}^g  \frac{dx_i^2+dy_i^2}{y_i^2}$. 
Let $\Gamma$ be the group of isometries of $\mathfrak{h}^g$. Let $\widetilde{\Gamma}$ be the group fitting in the following short exact sequence:
$$
1\rightarrow PSL_2(\mathbf{R})^g\rightarrow \widetilde{\Gamma}\rightarrow S_g\times S_2^g\rightarrow 1 
$$
Here $S_g$ stands for the symmetric group of degree $g$. The group $S_g$ acts by
permuting the coordinates of $\mathfrak{h}^g$. The element $(0,\ldots,1,\ldots,0)\in S_2^g$, where $1$ is placed in the $i$-th coordinate, acts on 
$\mathfrak{h}^g$ as $z_j\mapsto z_j$ if $j\neq i$ and $z_i\mapsto -\overline{z}_i$.

Clearly $\widetilde{\Gamma}\leq\Gamma$. I would expect $\widetilde{\Gamma}=\Gamma$.

**Q:**  Is there a reference in the literature where such a result is proved?

Comment: The conclusion is certainly correct, and has been known at least since Siegel's early work. Possibly his "advanced analytic number theory" does this (it's just Schwarz' lemma). I heard it as old-standard fact in 1976 in a course given by Shimura...